# Limit Add HTML Element inside div using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Using this javascript able add any amount of text field by clicking Add option.
I want to stop showing **Add Option** After 6 text field added. How can i limit it after 6?
Any help?

```js
$('.add').click(function() {
      $('.block:last').before(' <div class="block"><input type="text" /><span 
        class = "remove" > Remove Option < /span></div > ');
      });

    $('body').on('click', '.remove', function() {
      $(this).parent('.block').remove();
    });
```

```css
.block {
  display: block;
}

enter code here input {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
HTML

<div class="optionBox">
  <div class="block">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="block"> <span class="add">Add Option</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9tbet1xt/)

Comment: Use a counter variable and if counter > 6 dont add the values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a variable, which will store counts, increase it while adding `input` and decrease it while removing `input` and hide `button` accordingly

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var i = 0;

  $('.add').click(function() {
    if (i < 5) {
      $('.block:last').before(' <div class="block"><input type="text" /><span class="remove">Remove Option</span></div>');
    }

    i++
    hidebtn()
  });

  $('body').on('click', '.remove', function() {
    $(this).parent('.block').remove();

    i--
    hidebtn()
  });

  function hidebtn() {
    if (i >= 5) {
      $('.add').hide();
    } else $('.add').show();
  }
})
```

```css
.block {
  display: block;
}

input {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="optionBox">
  <div class="block">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="block"> <span class="add">Add Option</span>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.  But when i remove one field and i cant add another fileds to complete 6?

Comment: @BhuwanBhatt Corrected

Comment: @AbhishekPandey Good job but I dont get it why you start at 0. it makes no sence.

Comment: if I don't define `0`, it will throw error of undefined

Comment: @AbhishekPandey No I mean start at 1. Because we already have one input box.

Answer (score 4):

You **don't** need to create any variable. You can simply use `$(".block").length` to check how many inputs are present:

```js
$('body').on('click', '.add', function() {
  if ($(".block").length <= 6) {
    $('.block:last').before(' <div class="block"><input type="text" /><span class="remove">Remove Option</span></div>');
  }

  $(".block").length > 6 ? $('.add').hide() : $('.add').show();

});

$('body').on('click', '.remove', function() {
  $(this).parent('.block').remove();
  $('.add').show();
});
```

```css
.block {
  display: block;
}

input {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="optionBox">
  <div class="block">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="block"> <span class="add">Add Option</span>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have updated the fiddle. Please check below link.
[working code updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9tbet1xt/2/)

Steps :-

1. Use counter `var inputs = 0;`
2. Increment its value in add function.
3. Decrement its value in remove function.

Comment: Great Working fine.Thanks. Is there have any options to hide "Add Option"
After 6 field added?

Answer (score 1):

I updated your fiddle. please check below.

```
https://jsfiddle.net/Negirox/9tbet1xt/5/
```

please update your js.

```
var counter=0;
$('.add').click(function () {
if(counter<5)
{
 $('.block:last').before(' <div class="block"><input type="text" /><span class="remove">Remove Option</span></div>');
 counter++;
}
  else
  {
   alert("You exceeded a limit");
  }
});

$('body').on('click', '.remove', function () {
  $(this).parent('.block').remove();
  counter--;
});
```

Comment: Beat me by a minute :)

Comment: @raghav710 luck by chance :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep track of the current number of fields using a `counter` variable (or even better to avoid the nasty global. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48395047/2102114))

**HTML**

```
<div class="optionBox">
  <div class="block">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <div id="adderButton" class="block">
     <span class="add">Add Option</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var counter = 0;
// good to declare constants like this to avoid "magic numbers" in code
var LIMIT = 5;
$('.add').click(function () {
   if(counter < LIMIT){
     $('.block:last').before(' <div class="block"><input type="text" /><span class="remove">Remove Option</span></div>');
     counter += 1;
   }
   else {
    // dont show the option if we have exceeded the count
    $("#adderButton").hide();
   }
});

$('body').on('click', '.remove', function () {
    $(this).parent('.block').remove();
    counter -= 1;
    $("#adderButton").hide();
});
```

**UPDATE**

Since all other answers give readymade solutions to the OP's question. I'd like to enhance mine into a tutorial on how to solve similar problems for anyone interested.

**Problem:**

Dynamically add and remove elements upto a certain limit in JQuery

**Points to ponder**

1. When limit is reached, hide "adding" button and prevent adding further elements
2. If limit is not reached, show add button and allow adding further

The allow/disallow logic is based on the LIMIT that you specify. Here are some scenarios

1. While LIMIT has not been reached, show the Add option. Add 1 to the count (implicitly or explicitly)
2. If LIMIT has been reached, remove the add button
3. If an element is removed then the current no. of elements is < LIMIT, so *show* the Add option

Comment: Happy to help. Since all other answers already give you the solution you need, I'll be modifying mine into a tutorial on how to solve similar problems so its helpful in the future

Answer (score 1):

Did it with a if statement and increment-decrement values...

```js
var count = 0;
$('.add').click(function () {
if(count<6) {
    $('.block:last').before(' <div class="block"><input type="text" /><span class="remove">Remove Option</span></div>');
    alert(count);
    count++;
    if (count==5) {
     $('.add').hide();
    }
    } 
});

$('body').on('click', '.remove', function () {
    $(this).parent('.block').remove();
    $('.add').show();
    alert(count);
    count--;
});
```

```css
.block {
    display: block;
}
input {
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
}
span {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="optionBox">
    <div class="block">
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="block"> <span class="add">Add Option</span>

    </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:** Added the hide/show Add input functionality

Answer (score 0):

Its Quite Simple.

```js
var i=1;
$('.add').click(function () {
if(i>=6){

}else{
i = i+1;
 $('.block:last').before(' <div class="block"><input type="text" /><span class="remove">Remove Option</span></div>');
}
});

$('body').on('click', '.remove', function () {
    i = i-1;
    $(this).parent('.block').remove();
});
```

```css
.block {
    display: block;
}
input {
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
}
span {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="optionBox">
    <div class="block">
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="block"> <span class="add">Add Option</span>

    </div>
</div>
```